# Сравнить сумму значений 2 массивов

Tags: javascript

Задание:

Роботы, которые будут переносить за день наибольший суммарный вес грузов будут отобраны на продажу. Мы будем сравнивать результаты роботов попарно compareRobots, сравниваться будет сумма веса всех грузов, которые перенес каждый робот (firstRobotResults, secondRobotResults) в день.

Пример:

```
compareRobots([12, 4, 13], [1, 1, 4, 5, 12]) === 'First robot for sale!' - 29 > 23
compareRobots([9, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4, 5, 12]) === 'Both robots for sale!' - 25 = 25
compareRobots([1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 4, 5]) === 'Second robot for sale!' - 8 < 11
```

Мое решение:

```
function compareRobots(firstRobotResults, secondRobotResults) {

if(firstRobotResults>secondRobotResults){

return 'First robot for sale!';
     }else if(firstRobotResults<secondRobotResults){
     return "Second robot for sale!";
}else if(firstRobotResults=secondRobotResults){
     return 'Both robots for sale!';
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function compareRobots(first, last){
    if(getSum(first) > getSum(last)) return 'First robot for sale!';
    if(getSum(first) == getSum(last)) return 'Both robots for sale!';
    if(getSum(first) < getSum(last)) return 'Second robot for sale!';
}

function getSum(arr){
    return arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0);
}
```